# How to get selected month and year from big calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

Is there any way to get the value of the selected month and year from big calendar(the one that is being currently displayed)? Also when I click on previous/next button in the month view, the value should also get updated so that I get the selected month.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use onNavigate to get the value of the selected month and the year.

```
<BigCalendar
  selectable
  events={events}
  defaultView='week'
  defaultDate={this.state.selectedDay}
  onNavigate={() => { this.state.selectedDay }}
/>
```

Comment: Can U pls more elaborate it like how can i use it to get that particular displayed month and year